# Web-разработка в Linux

Tags: веб-программирование, linux

**Доброго дня!**

Все, кто сталкивался с веб разработкой, знают, что немаловажным( а порой и основным ) аспектом является выбранная среда разработки(редактор кода), в которой и происходит написание кода. Те, кто разрабатывают в Windows, наверняка столкивались с одним из самых прекрасных редакторов кода - DreamWeaver`ом. Он настолько удобен, что разработка в нем( как clienside, так и serverside части ) становится в разы приятнее. Так, собственно, вопрос, существует ли что-то хоть немного приближенное к DreamWeaver в Linux-системах? Если нет, то что предпочитаете использовать вы?

**P.S** Пока приходится "корячиться" в SubLime Text 2. Он не так уж и плох( подсветка синтаксиса и все такое ), но он недостаточно удобен, по крайней мере, для меня.

Comment: WebStorm

Comment: eclipse, netbeans - имеет смысл начать с них

Comment: >Все, кто сталкивался с веб разработкой, знают, что немаловажным( а порой и основным ) аспектом является выбранная среда разработки(редактор кода), в которой и происходит написание кода. Те, кто разрабатывают в Windows, наверняка столкивались с одним из самых прекрасных редакторов кода - DreamWeaver`ом Он настолько удобен, что разработка в нем( как clienside, так и serverside части ) становится в разы приятнее.

прочтя эти строки, невольно подумал, что это реклама очередного видеокурса какого-нибудь Евгения Попова

Answer (score 3):

Не понимаю восторга от Дримвивера, обычный редактор. В нём верстать удобно стало, код как то по другому выглядит??? Я тоже когда на линуксы пересаживался, то искал аналоги виндовых программ - но это путь в никуда. Тут нужно мозги перестраивать под юниксы - тут принцип одна программа выполняет одну функцию, поэтому особо больших многофункциональных комбайнов, а тем более с визуализацией всего, ты не найдёшь.
Вообще если выбрал Линукс как платформу для разработки, то отвыкай от вредных программ, которые пишут код за тебя.
Был на винде пользовался нотепадом++ - больше вставляло. 
Если юзать как Дримвивер - то саблайм с плагинами, geany. Если же ИДЕ нужна, то Аптана или платный PhpStorm. 
Что мне сейчас не хватает в SublimeText, то это автоконплишн пользовательских методов или методов твоего фреймворка, которые могут не находится в текущем файле, но включены в проект инклюдами. Для этого нужна ИДЕ. А как саблайм подстроить под ПХП лови: [10 Crucial Sublime Text 2 Plugins for the PHP Craftsman](http://www.neverstopbuilding.com/sublime-plugins-for-php)

Так же можно поискать модули под другие задачи, там их очень много. Удачи )

Comment: Совсем немножко исправить ситуацию с Sublime Text и автодополнением можно с использованием ctags: [CTags](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags) и [Sublime CTags PHP](https://github.com/erichard/SublimeCTagsPHP). Но IDE они не заменят, конечно.

Comment: Это равносильно тому, что говорить, мол, отвыкай от современных фреймворков для разработки, ведь они удобнее, чем древние тулзы из нулевых:

    отвыкай от вредных программ, которые пишут код за тебя

"Вредные" IDE, которые помогают при написании кода, лишь экономят время.

Comment: О современных инструментах и вредных программах - это я о себе, во времена моей работы с Delphy... это я о своей боли, т.к. так и не научился писать на нём и в то время думал, что язык должен скрывать хардкорные вещи от меня. Ох, как я ошибался - программирования на кубиках не бывает. Программируя на том же ПХП полезно задуматся как исполняет твой код интерпретатор. Согласен, что инструменты должны быть современны, но не должны быть в ущерб прогрессу программиста.
xEdelweiss, спасибо за ссылки на плагины.

Comment: @0xFF не совсем так. IDE может ещё навязывать стиль разработки. Это не плохо и не хорошо -- надо смотреть конкретные условия. Если эта IDE'я подходит для Ваших задач -- отлично. Нет -- ну так на нет и суда нет. Такие ситуации могут возникать и достаточно редко.

Answer (score 2):

KDevelop есть еще. тоже хорошая вещь.
Не только код править можно еще и к удаленкам подключаться по ftp ssh.

Так что могу его посоветовать.

А вообще можно и NetBeans поставить, делов то, он под unix тоже есть, и работает отлично.

Answer (score 1):

Для sublime Text существует куча плагинов, которые упрощают процесс разработки, главное найти нужные.

А если советовать, то конечно же VIM!

Answer (score 0):

приближенного к dreamweaver нету. поглядите на komodo ide, eclipse